# when listview's item is click,how to make its view color to be red, others is black?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

please look at the picture.

[image]
this is listview, its item is a textview, I want to result is that when I click the item ,its textview's color turn to red,and all of others have no selected is black.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView one = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
            one.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bb0e0e"));
        }
    });
```

I try like that, but it will when you click the item ,all of you click item will turn to be red. how can I do for my want?

Comment: adapter class >???

Comment: you mean I should show my adapter?

Comment: Just try to check it here link : https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-listview-selection-color.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**define a global int variable**

```
int tempLocation;

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
   {
       tempLocation = position
      // adapter notify dataset change
      adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
    }
});
```

And override the getView method of your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

    if (position == tempLocation) {
        // set your color
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After setcolor refresh listview

```
   iew.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView one = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
        one.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bb0e0e"));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```